# DataBinding over a property in viewModel

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

surely this question has beed debated thousand of time, but I do not find any suitable solution to my need. I am new to SilverLIght and I intended to start well using MVVM.
therefore I did the following view model :

```
public class MyViewModel 
    {
          private IRepository _Repository;
          public string CountText { get; set; }
          public MyViewModel (IRepository repository)
        {

            _Repository = repository;
            CountText = "test ctor";
        }

         public void MyButtonCommand()
        {
            _Repository.GetResult((Result r) => MyActionAsync(r), (Exception e) => ManageException(e));
        }

 public void MyActionAsync(SchedeConsunitiviResult result)
        {
            CountText = string.Format("{0} items", result.Count);
        }

        public void ManageException(Exception e)
        {
            //to log the exception here and display some alert message
        }

}
```

and here my xaml :

```
<sdk:Label Content="{Binding Path=CountText, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="3" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,142,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

The first instanciation of CountText is visible in the Label. But the second one after the async method does not change the content of the LAbel. Should I add some mechanism like PropertyChanged in order to tell the view this property has changed? if so, how can I do that using xaml only?

thx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and notify that your property has changed with the EventHandler.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string countText;

    public string CountText        
    {
        get { return this.countText; }
        set { this.countText = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("CountText"); }
    }

    .....snip.....

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] properties)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            foreach (string property in properties)
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you do need a mechanism like PropertyChanged in your viewmodel

Comment: thx for the answer I used Arcturus code successfully, but you were right too!